# Unable to open connection using oledb for csv file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, csv

I am using this function to get dataset from csv file:

```
public static DataSet GetDataset(string filePathName, string fileName, string fieldNames)
    {
        OleDbConnection CSVConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePathName + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';");
        OleDbCommand CSVCommand = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT " + fieldNames + " FROM [" + fileName + "]", CSVConnection);
        OleDbDataAdapter CSVAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(CSVCommand);
        DataSet CSVDataSet = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            CSVConnection.Open();
            CSVAdapter.Fill(CSVDataSet);
            return CSVDataSet;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return CSVDataSet;
        }
        finally
        {
            CSVConnection.Close();
            CSVConnection.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

But, I am getting following error on server while reading csv file using oledb provider

> Message: Unspecified error
>       StackTrace: at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningObject) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() at DB.GetDataset(String
>   filePathName, String fileName, String fieldNames)

Comment: Please show us your code work.

Comment: OleDbConnection CSVConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filePathName + ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,)';");

Answer (score 0):

A look at template of your connection string will help figure out the issue.
Try to have a look at [Connection string formats here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)